# Python 3.8.3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: python-3.8

OS == RH7. Installed Python 3.8.3 from source. Getting the below stack trace. Please advise.

```
pip install -q -e .[dev] --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager
pre-commit install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/degenaro/venv/bin/pre-commit", line 5, in <module>
    from pre_commit.main import main
  File "/home/degenaro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pre_commit/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pre_commit.commands.autoupdate import autoupdate
  File "/home/degenaro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pre_commit/commands/autoupdate.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pre_commit.clientlib import InvalidManifestError
  File "/home/degenaro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pre_commit/clientlib.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pre_commit.error_handler import FatalError
  File "/home/degenaro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pre_commit/error_handler.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pre_commit.store import Store
  File "/home/degenaro/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pre_commit/store.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/opt/Python-3.8.3/Lib/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/opt/Python-3.8.3/Lib/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
make: *** [develop] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The distribution you got for red hat probably didn't include it in the standard library. Try installing libsqlite3-dev (sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev) then rebuild/install your project with the correct flags i.e. --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions

Comment: This fix worked for me. In my case, it had to do with installing a version of Python using pyenv.

Comment: Does that mean I have to re-compile Python after installing the module? My Python is installed via tools, not download and build on my own. What should I do?

Comment: I had to install `libsqlite3-dev` and recompile python (in my case, `pyenv uninstall 3.8.9 && pyenv install 3.8.9`) and it worked